How to handle a user with multiple unregistered accounts posting low quality answers?
We appear to have a user that semi-regularly posts low quality answers (either lacking in sources or simply paraphrasing other answers). They seem to now operate under two different usernames (having the same posting style). Since these are unregistered accounts, answer bans won't take effect because it creates a new profile each time they return.
Is there any way to deal with this approach or do we simply have to keep flagging and deleting the low quality posts?

Technically "sockpuppet" accounts run by the same actual user aren't in and of themselves against the rules. However, using a sockpuppet account to get around a suspension, boost the reputation of other accounts of yours, artificially de-boost others, or repost removed content, is against the rules.
If you suspect something like that is going on, flag one of the posts, and tell the moderators what you think the other account is. We have tools we can use to double check if that's the case. Also if it happens enough, we (I?) can even start proactively looking for new socks before they have a chance to post much, if anything at all. Sock puppetmasters tend to have tells on their accounts, and we (I) regularly look through our new user registrations for any new socks from habitual puppetmasters.
In the specific example described in the question, it sounds likely the poster may be using the socks to get around either a suspension for low quality posts, or an automatic posting ban due to low reputation. So that would indeed be worthy of bringing to the attention of moderators via a flag.

I'd like to add that I've had users do this before, and the accounts quite often end up being completely unrelated when I look into it. Except for SE's resident Nazi troll. People who think they've spotted a sock for that one are rarely wrong.
